# Finding ways to specify Functional Specification Verifiable-c

Tags: verifiable-c

I'm just getting started with verifiable-c work and am struggling with generating functional specifications for the C code I've written. My basic example I'm working with is (C code) simply

```
int xor(int v1, int v2) {
  return v1 ^ v2;
}
```

and I'm having difficulty putting together the 
    Definition xor_spec
section.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Definition xor_spec :=
 DECLARE _xor
 WITH v1 : int, v2: int
 PRE [ _v1 OF tint, _v2 OF tint]
    PROP () 
    LOCAL (temp _v1 (Vint v1); temp _v2 (Vint v2))
    SEP ()
 POST [ tint ]
    PROP() 
    LOCAL (temp ret_temp (Vint (Int.xor v1 v2))) 
    SEP().
```

That version uses "int" values, that is, 32-bit
integers from CompCert's Int module.  Usually I like
to specify my functions on the mathematical integers;
that style of specification would like like:

```
Definition xor_spec2 :=
 DECLARE _xor
 WITH v1 : Z, v2: Z
 PRE [ _v1 OF tint, _v2 OF tint]
    PROP (0 <= v1 <= Int.max_unsigned; 0 <= v2 <= Int.max_unsigned) 
    LOCAL (temp _v1 (Vint (Int.repr v1)); temp _v2 (Vint (Int.repr v2)))
    SEP ()
 POST [ tint ]
    PROP() 
    LOCAL (temp ret_temp (Vint (Int.repr (Z.lxor v1 v2)))) 
    SEP().
```

Caveat:  I haven't run either of these through Coq, so they
might have minor typos.  And I haven't studied Z.lxor enough
to make sure it's what you'd want.

Comment: So either option pushes through the first check, but when I try to prove them (or even a simple 
int xor () { return 0; }
method) fails when I try to do forward on the goals.

Comment: More specifically, the goal
semax Delta
  (PROP ( )  LOCAL (temp _tmp (Vint (Int.repr 0)); temp _bit (Vint bit); temp _key (Vint key))  SEP ())
  (Sreturn (Some (Etempvar _tmp tint))) POSTCONDITION
 fails to continue on a 'forward'

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the C code?  From your last comment, it appears that you have local variables "tmp", "bit", "key", but I don't see them in the C program.

Comment: 'int designInt(int bit, int invKey) {'

Comment: `int designInt(int bit, int invKey) {
    int tmp = 0;
    return tmp;
}`

Comment: Figured it out, had naming issues.